# Laravel while empty collection add new parameters in filters to get notEmpty collection

Tags: laravel

I have this query who return an empty collection with the filter param `categorie_compet_id` with value `1`.

while the collection is empty i need to update this id in order to get a notEmpty collection.

The `categorie_compet_id` can go from `1` to `10`.

How could I do this properly?

```php
$arbitres = Licencies::getArbitres();
    $arbitres->load('rencontreOfficiels');
    $arbitres->load('divisions');

$arbitres = $arbitres->reject(function ($arbitre) use ($rencontre) {
    return $arbitre->rencontreOfficiels->contains(function ($rencontreOfficiels) use ($rencontre) {
        return $rencontreOfficiels->rencontre_id === $rencontre->id;
    });
})->filter(function ($arbitre) {
    return $arbitre->divisions->contains('categorie_compet_id', 1);
})->filter(function($arbitre) {
    return $arbitre->level >= 3;
});
```

### UPDATE

```php
$arbitres->load('rencontreOfficiels');
$arbitres->load('divisions');

$arbitres = $arbitres->reject(function ($arbitre) use ($rencontre) {
    return $arbitre->rencontreOfficiels->contains(function ($rencontreOfficiels) use ($rencontre) {
        return $rencontreOfficiels->rencontre_id === $rencontre->id;
    });
})->filter(function ($arbitre) {
    return $arbitre->divisions->contains('categorie_compet_id', 1);
})->filter(function($arbitre) use ($rencontre) {
    return $arbitre->doesnthave('rencontreOfficiels')->where('rencontreOfficiels.dt_rencontre' , $rencontre->dt_rencontre);
});

//on génére les meilleurs arbitres
for ($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
    $filtered = $arbitres->filter(function ($arbitre) use ($i) {
        return $arbitre->level <= $i;
    });

    if ($filtered->isNotEmpty()) {
        $arbitres = $filtered;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here's my `getArbitres` method in model:

```php
public static function getArbitres(){
    $all_licences = Licencies::whereIn('activite_licencie_id' , [24,25,50,80])
        ->where('valid_licence_id' , 3)
        ->where('saison_id' , self::getSaison()->id)
        ->where('dispo' , 1)
        ->get();

    return $licences;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a for loop.

```php
$arbitres = $arbitres->reject(function ($arbitre) use ($rencontre) {
    return $arbitre->rencontreOfficiels->contains(function ($rencontreOfficiels) use ($rencontre) {
        return $rencontreOfficiels->rencontre_id === $rencontre->id;
    });

for ($i = 3; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $filtered = $arbitres->filter(function ($arbitre) use ($i) {
        return $arbitre->level >= $i;
    });

    if ($filtered->isNotEmpty()) {
        $arbitres = $filtered;
        break;
    }
}
```

Simply replace `10` by your max level.

### Update

You should be filtering your `$arbitres` collection from the database when retrieving instead of filtering them after.

```php
$arbitres = App\Arbitres::whereHas('rencontreOfficiels', function ($query) use ($rencontre) {
    $query->where('rencontre_id', $rencontre->id);
})->whereDoesntHave('rencontreOfficiels', function ($query) use ($rencontre) {
    $query->where('dt_rencontre', $rencontre->dt_rencontre);
})whereHas('divisions', function ($query) {
    $query->where('categorie_complet_id', 1);
})->get();
```

### Update 2

Since you cannot filter the `$arbitres` upon retrieval, you can filter them like this:

```php
$arbitres = $arbitres->reject(function ($arbitre) use ($rencontre) {
    return $arbitre->rencontreOfficiels->contains(function ($rencontreOfficiels) use ($rencontre) {
        return $rencontreOfficiels->rencontre_id === $rencontre->id;
    });
})->filter(function ($arbitre){
    return $arbitre->divisions->contains('categorie_compet_id', 1);
})->filter(function($arbitre) use ($rencontre){
    return ! $arbitre->rencontreOfficiels->contains('dt_rencontre' , $rencontre->dt_rencontre);
});
```

Comment: that's what i'm looking for i will try that when i'm at the office and i let you know many thanks

Comment: @MathieuMourareau Sure :)

Comment: that's work man many thanks, i added a new filter before the loop in order to don't get arbitres who are already in rencontreOfficiels relation in the same day but it's not working

Comment: return $arbitre->doesnthave('rencontreOfficiels'); has no effect i should get only two items

Comment: @MathieuMourareau That's because your filter is returning an object, which is a positive value, hence passes the filter test.

Comment: @MathieuMourareau Have a look at my update. It is going to improve in term of performance to filter the records before retrieving them from the database.

Comment: i can't because generate the initial collection like $arbitres = Licencies::getArbitres(); i update the post

Comment: @MathieuMourareau Can you show the `getArtbitres()` method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208004/discussion-between-mathieu-mourareau-and-chin-leung).